# INSERT return type?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, return-type, sql-function

I realize "an [`INSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) command returns a command tag," but what's the return type of a command tag?

I.e., what should be the return type of a [query language (SQL) function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) that ends with an `INSERT`?

For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION messages_new(integer, integer, text) RETURNS ??? AS $$
    INSERT INTO messages (from, to, body) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Sure, I can just specify the function's return type as `integer` and either add `RETURNING 1` to the `INSERT` or `SELECT 1;` after the `INSERT`. But, I'd prefer to keep things as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most APIs specify that DML statements return the number of records affected if there are no errors, and negative numbers as error codes if there are errors that prevent the code from executing successfully. This is a good practice to incorporate into your designs.

Answer (score 3):

If the inserted values are of any interest, as when they are processed before inserting, you can return a row of type `messages`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION messages_new(integer, integer, text) 
RETURNS messages AS $$
    INSERT INTO messages (from, to, body) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
    returning *;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And get it like this

```
select *
from messages_new(1,1,'text');
```

Answer (score 2):

A return type of `void` works.

```
CREATE FUNCTION messages_new(integer, integer, text) RETURNS void AS $$
    INSERT INTO messages (from, to, body) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```